# bring (something) to the fore. put the object to the back

Tags: phrase-usage

https://www.nytimes.com/2018/12/16/world/europe/france-national-front-yellow-vests.html

> Mr. Briois’s critics say his motivation is obvious: The hundreds of
>   thousands of protesters are France’s newest and most powerful
>   grass-roots force, threatening the presidency of Mr. Macron and
>   **bringing to the fore the plight** of the country’s struggling middle class and working poor.

I see the idiom [bring (something) to the fore](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bring+to+the+fore).
Why does it can put the object to the back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the object is "way too long" to be placed right after "bringing". The object of the sentence is not just `plight` but "the plight of the country’s struggling middle class and working poor". If we put this object right after the predicate and put "to the fore" at the very end, it'll be grammatically correct, but it's better to say "bringing to the fore" first so that the reader can immediately understand what idiom is being used.

Comment: Could you please show me the rule about "objects can be placed to the back if it is too long"?

Comment: @马化腾 Unfortunately, I don't have any grammar books at hand now, and I can't cite any rule. But I just rely on my experience giving the answer. In fact, placing the direct object after another object happens quite often. And usually it's done to avoid possible confusion, when the object is quite long. But technically it should be used right after the predicate. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: @马化腾 Here is another example http://www.jdrf.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Investigator_Logo_Letter.pdf. Usually we say "share something with somebody", don't we? But here you'll read "we'd like to share with you some exciting news about JDRF." Why is that? Because the object is quite long. It's better to put "with you" before the object "not to forget about it" later.